# Finding the first time a value shows up in a list efficiently

Tags: r

I was trying to solve a problem where there was a long list that had a variable amount of numbers at each index.  The goals was to say what was the earliest index at which every number appeared.  So if a 15 shows up at index 45 and 78 in the list, then I should return that 15 is located first at 48.  In the original problem this went on with a list of length 10,000, so doing this fast was helpful.

Originally I tried to work with the existing list structure and did something like this, which at 10,000 lines very slow.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(100, sample(100, sample(10, 1)))
cbind(value = 1:100,
      index = sapply(1:100, function(i) which.max(sapply(x, function(x) i %in% x))))
```

Eventually I tried converting the data in to a data.table, which worked much better but I always wondered if there was a better way to go about solving the problem.  Like was the default list structure inherently inefficient or was there a better way I could have worked with it?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(100, sample(100, sample(10, 1)))
dt <- data.table(index = rep(1:100, sapply(x, length)), value = unlist(x))
dt[,.(index = first(index)),value][order(value)]
```

Here's the full dataset from the original problem if that's helpful.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(memoise)
library(data.table)

jgo <- function(n) {
  if (isPrimeRcpp(n) | n == 1) return (n)
  div <- divisorsRcpp(n)
  div <- div[-c(1, length(div))]
  div <- Map(function(a, b) c(a, b), div, rev(div))
  div2 <- lapply(div, function(x) lapply(jgo(x[1]), c, x[2]))
  unique(lapply(c(div, unlist(div2, recursive = FALSE)), sort))
}

jgo <- memoise(jgo)  

x <- lapply(1:12500, function(x) x - sapply(jgo(x), sum) + sapply(jgo(x), length))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach that uses `match` to find the first indices. This slightly outperforms the other suggested approaches and produces similar output as in OP's question:

```r
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(100, sample(100, sample(10, 1)))

## use match to find first indices
first_indices_match <- function(x) {
  seq_x <- 1:length(x)
  matrix(c(seq_x, rep(seq_x, lengths(x))[match(seq_x, unlist(x))]), 
      ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("value", "index"))) 
}

head(first_indices_match(x))
#>      value index
#> [1,]     1     1
#> [2,]     2     7
#> [3,]     3    45
#> [4,]     4    38
#> [5,]     5    31
#> [6,]     6     7

## data.table approach
library(data.table)

first_indices_dt <- function(x) {
  dt <- data.table(index = rep(seq_along(x), sapply(x, length)), value = unlist(x))
  dt[,.(index = first(index)),value][order(value)]

}

head(first_indices_dt(x))
#>    value index
#> 1:     1     1
#> 2:     2     7
#> 3:     3    45
#> 4:     4    38
#> 5:     5    31
#> 6:     6     7
```

**Benchmarks**

```r
## stack + remove duplicate approach
first_indices_shree <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- seq_len(length(x))
  (d <- stack(x))[!duplicated(d$values), ]
}

## benchmarks several list sizes
bnch <- bench::press(
    n_size = c(100, 1E3, 1E4),
    {
      x <- replicate(n_size, sample(n_size, sample(10, 1)))
      bench::mark(
          match = first_indices_match(x),
          shree = first_indices_shree(x),
          dt = first_indices_dt(x),
          check = FALSE
      )
    }  
)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#>   expression n_size      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 match         100  18.17µs   21.2µs   45639.    637.3KB    27.4 
#> 2 shree         100 361.88µs 411.06µs    2307.   106.68KB    11.1 
#> 3 dt            100 759.17µs 898.26µs     936.   264.58KB     8.51
#> 4 match        1000 158.34µs  169.9µs    5293.   164.15KB    30.8 
#> 5 shree        1000   1.54ms   1.71ms     567.   412.52KB    13.2 
#> 6 dt           1000   1.19ms    1.4ms     695.   372.13KB    10.7 
#> 7 match       10000   3.09ms   3.69ms     255.     1.47MB    15.9 
#> 8 shree       10000  18.06ms  18.95ms      51.5    4.07MB    12.9 
#> 9 dt          10000   5.65ms   6.33ms     149.     2.79MB    20.5
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach +1. Here's a **generalized** and slightly faster version of your answer -`first_indices_match2 <- function(x) {
  u <- unlist(x)
  i <- rep(seq_along(x), times = lengths(x))
  data.frame(
    values = unique(u),
    index = i[match(unique(u), u)]
  )
}`.

Comment: Thanks @Shree! I benchmarked your suggestion, but it seems to be a bit slower for larger sized lists. I edited the response with the fastest version of this approach I could think of (at this moment).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply stack the list into a dataframe and remove duplicated values. This will give you the first index for all values in the list.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(100, sample(100, sample(10, 1)))

names(x) <- seq_along(x)
first_indices <- (d <- stack(x))[!duplicated(d$values), ]

head(first_indices)
  values ind
1     38   1
2     57   1
3     90   1
5     94   2
6     65   2
7      7   3
```

You can now lookup index for any value you want using `%in%` -

```
subset(first_indices, values %in% c(37,48))

   values ind
11     37   3
40     48   8
```

**Benchmarks -**

```
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(1000, sample(1000, sample(10, 1)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Shree = first_indices(x),
  JamesB = cbind(value = 1:1000,
      index = sapply(1:1000, function(i) which.max(sapply(x, function(x) i %in% x))))
)

Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min         lq        mean    median        uq       max neval
 Shree    2.3488    2.74855    4.171323    3.0577    4.7752   17.0743   100
JamesB 1750.4806 1904.79150 2519.912936 1994.9814 3282.5957 5966.1011   100
```